# I think my ISP is blocking acsess to my server outside my network

Tags: ubuntu-server, dmz

My friend gave me a nice desktop computer. I decided to install Ubuntu server and use it as a server. I have a ssh server, web server,minecraft server, and sometimes a team speak server running on it. I have it running in a DMZ on our router. Everything worked fine for a while, but then one day, the server was only accessible from my local network, even when using my public IP address.

EDIT:I think my ISP might be blocking all ports. How can I tell? How can I get around this?

Comment: Sometimes your external IP address can change - have you checked it is still the same as when your server could be accessed from outside your local network?

Comment: Yes. I can even use my external IP inside my local network to connect to the server.

Comment: OK, so the next step is to check your ISP's terms and conditions to see if they state that they block some ports or simply do not allow running a server.

Comment: It says not to use web server sites, But it seems to be blocking everything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it involves circumvention of restrictions in violation of ISP terms of service. Please contact your ISP or consider switching to a business account which allows operating a public server.

Comment: @DragonLord - there is no indication that this is a breach of any terms and conditions of the ISP - and it is possible the ISP is at fault.  Also, I am probably wrong, but I can't see where there is any prohibition on asking questions which may be a violation of terms of service.

Comment: @davidgo: The last comment from the OP indicates otherwise. See also: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/533/handling-questions-clearly-trying-to-break-some-kind-of-policy-tos-etc

Comment: @DragonLord - thank you for that, but the link you provided is entirely unclear that these kinds of questions should be blocked.  Also  it may be a breach of consumer/net-neutrality law for the ISP to block it - particularly as some things which are servers are not obvious to a typical end user, but are things they would expect to work - for example, P2P apps, VPN endpoints, Remote Viewer/Control software.  [ In my opinion, an SSH server falls into this catagory - they are not massive bandwidth consumers or meant for all-and-sundry to connect to].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ISP is blocking all incoming ports, you can get round this by using a VPN - although you will need to ensure the VPN provider provides you with a unique IP address you can tunnel back through (or equivalent).

You can also better diagnose what is going on by using TCPDump to see what traffic is arriving at your computer - this could help rule out problems with the setup of the PC.